# usage of "flavour"

Tags: word-usage

I came across the unfamiliar use of **flavor** in a [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-60492134)

> Here is a **flavour** of the comments:
>
> > "Putin is awesome!"
> > "I support Russia, oppose US. That's all I wanna say."
> > "America always wants to create mess in the world!"

But as far as I know, **flavor** means the distinctive taste of something.
Could somebody tell me what it means in this context?

Comment: This is an example of a figurative expression, which shouldn't be taken literally:  "a flavour of something" = an example or an idea of something.

Comment: The preceding paragraph in the BBC story makes clear that "The [Chinese] state press has its own accounts on Weibo and controls the responses to its posts about Russia and Ukraine." The comments quoted are the only type allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use 'flavour' ('flavor' in US) in a figurative sense (that is, not to do with physically tasting something) to mean 'a general idea of what something is like', or 'a brief experience of something'.

*The book gives you a flavour of what alternative therapy is about.*

> :Meaning of flavour in English
> flavour noun (US flavor)
>
> an idea or quick experience of something:
> *To give you a flavour of what the book is like Jilly is going to read out a
> brief extract.*

[Flavour (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flavour)

We can also use the noun 'taste' in this way.
*You can come to our stable and get a taste of horseriding.*

The idea is that we get a brief idea of what something is like, without making a deep study of it. The figurative comparison is with e.g. touching a food item and then licking your finger. You know something of its taste or flavour without eating the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)